# Как уменьшить код, который меняет свойства numericUpDown?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как уменьшить код, который меняет свойства numericUpDown?

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            numericUpDownHPM1.Maximum = 1000;
            numericUpDownHPM1.Minimum = 1;
            numericUpDownHPM1.DecimalPlaces = 0;
            numericUpDownHPM1.Increment = 1;
            numericUpDownHPM1.Value = 100;
            label101.Visible = true;
            numericUpDownHPP1.Maximum = 1000;
            label102.Visible = true;

            numericUpDownMPM1.Maximum = 1000;
            numericUpDownMPM1.Minimum = 1;
            numericUpDownMPM1.DecimalPlaces = 0;
            numericUpDownMPM1.Increment = 1;
            numericUpDownMPM1.Value = 100;
            label103.Visible = true;
            numericUpDownMPP1.Maximum = 1000;
            label104.Visible = true;

            numericUpDownStrM1.Maximum = 1000;
            numericUpDownStrM1.Minimum = 1;
            numericUpDownStrM1.DecimalPlaces = 0;
            numericUpDownStrM1.Increment = 1;
            numericUpDownStrM1.Value = 100;
            label111.Visible = true;
            numericUpDownStrP1.Maximum = 1000;
            label112.Visible = true;

            numericUpDownDefM1.Maximum = 1000;
            numericUpDownDefM1.Minimum = 1;
            numericUpDownDefM1.DecimalPlaces = 0;
            numericUpDownDefM1.Increment = 1;
            numericUpDownDefM1.Value = 100;
            label113.Visible = true;
            numericUpDownDefP1.Maximum = 1000;
            label114.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            numericUpDownHPM1.Maximum = 10;
            numericUpDownHPM1.Minimum = new decimal(new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 65536 });
            numericUpDownHPM1.DecimalPlaces = 1;
            numericUpDownHPM1.Increment = new decimal(new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 65536});
            numericUpDownHPM1.Value = 1;
            label101.Visible = false;
            numericUpDownHPP1.Maximum = 99999;
            label102.Visible = false;

            numericUpDownMPM1.Maximum = 10;
            numericUpDownMPM1.Minimum = new decimal(new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 65536 });
            numericUpDownMPM1.DecimalPlaces = 1;
            numericUpDownMPM1.Increment = new decimal(new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 65536 });
            numericUpDownMPM1.Value = 1;
            label103.Visible = false;
            numericUpDownMPP1.Maximum = 65535;
            label104.Visible = false;

            numericUpDownStrM1.Maximum = 10;
            numericUpDownStrM1.Minimum = new decimal(new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 65536 });
            numericUpDownStrM1.DecimalPlaces = 1;
            numericUpDownStrM1.Increment = new decimal(new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 65536 });
            numericUpDownStrM1.Value = 1;
            label111.Visible = false;
            numericUpDownStrP1.Maximum = 255;
            label112.Visible = false;

            numericUpDownDefM1.Maximum = 10;
            numericUpDownDefM1.Minimum = new decimal(new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 65536 });
            numericUpDownDefM1.DecimalPlaces = 1;
            numericUpDownDefM1.Increment = new decimal(new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 65536 });
            numericUpDownDefM1.Value = 1;
            label113.Visible = false;
            numericUpDownDefP1.Maximum = 255;
            label114.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Это только часть кода. Код в 10 раз больше, занимает много места.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как минимум, можно настройку в метод вынести:

```
public void SetUpElement(NumericUpDown item, int max, int min, int decPlaces, int increment, int value) {
     item.Maximum = max;
     item.Minimum = min;
     item.DecimalPlaces = decPlaces;
     item.Increment = increment;
     item.Value = value;
}
```

Теперь вместо 6 строк для настройки каждого элемента будет 1 вызов метода. К примеру, для `numericUpDownHPM1`:

```
SetUpElement(numericUpDownHPM1, 1000, 1, 0, 1, 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

Правильнее всего в данном случае описать модель (в случае [MVC](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/mvc/overview)) и привязать свойства контролов к ней. Модель ты создаёшь один раз для кажого набора элементов и инициализируешь всеми необходимыми зависимостями (н.п. минимальные и максимальные значения для каждого из вариантов). При переключении режима Checked/Unchecked, выставляешь соответствующий флажок в модели и она [начинает отдавать контролу новые значени](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)я.